# What do you call the energy that has been created by fear or happiness?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

There are times that we feel tired and weak and not able to get up and do something, in this situation:

- if we face a danger, like our house goes on fire, or become under attack,
- or remember that we have forgotten to do something very important,
- or we unexpectedly  hear our loved one is at the airport and needs to be picked up by us,
- or we have won a big prize and need to pick it up

in these cases, some kind of energy will be created in our body which we had not felt  before these incidents, and we imminently act upon these.

I don’t know if you can call it “emotional energy” or"unlocked energy" or"released energy", if not what do you call it?

Comment: You might call it adrenaline, though I don't know that it fits all of your examples.

Comment: What EFrog said. It's often called an *adrenaline **rush***.

Comment: _Hysterical or superhuman strength_ is related but it occurs in life and death situations. You have mild examples too.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact situation, the following are possible:

You might have **a {surge / rush} of adrenaline.**

Or you might feel **a wave of {anxiety / excitement / anger / nausea / revulsion}** [or some other visceral emotion].

There might be **a sick feeling in your stomach.**

Answer (score 0):

I call it **"new stamina"**

> stamina
>
> - "strength or power to endure fatigue, stress, etc." [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stamina)
> - "great physical or mental strength that allows you to continue doing something for a long time." [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stamina)

"I had to find new stamina to endure that situation".

Answer (score 0):

One name for it is **nervous energy**.

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nervous-energy) has

> **noun**
>
> an excess of energy that you have when you are apprehensive or worried
>
> - "The band gathered backstage, buzzing with nervous energy."
> - "the nervous energy of adolescence"
> - "Harness your nervous energy and transform it into vitality and enthusiasm."

I think the examples you give in the question are better than theirs.

Answer (score 0):

The adrenal cortex can mediate or cause a stress response by either producing or limiting  aldosterone and cortisol.

"Stress Response" is the medical definition of what you are talking about.